Can I use the old chimney as attic vent?
I removed a fireplace but the chimney remains. It’s a metal tube lined wood box from 1989 era. I want to cap it with wind turbine or solar attic fan to vent the attic . There are plenty of air intake holes around the exterior of the attic to let air in. The sheet metal will fit right over where existing chimney cap is
